# MS Excel | Need a formula that is able to identify the gap (number of 0s) between 2 1s in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the output of `AE:BC`

[image]

What I want to do is firstly identify the first occurrence of 1
Then I want to know if the next cell has 1 or zero, if it is a zero then I want to find when the next 1 will occur. This will be considered a gap.

If the columns are as follows:
1   0   0   1 then the gap is 2 and I want to know the number of gaps that occur in each array. It is possible to have multiple gaps in a single row so I would need a formula that can be dragged to get details of all gaps.
Please note that if there are no gaps between 1s and no 1s after a string of zeros till the end then it shouldn't be counted as a gap.

Stuck with it. Tried thinking of COUNTIFS and OFFSET but not sure how to get the required response.

Comment: So, from give sample how many gaps do you expect? Is it 3 or 2? Show your desired output also in screenshot.'

Comment: @Harun24hr if we are talking about the image, the number I want to see is 5 since that is the max gap between 1s

Comment: So you need to find the width of all gaps? Hoe do you want to display that, please include more details in your question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
=MAX(SCAN(0, yourcols,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v=1,0,IF(v=0,a+1,a))))
```

The SCAN formula passes an accumulator and each value of the array to the lambda which adds 1 for a zero or resets for a 1. This returns an array of values of which the max is your answer.

Comment: Trying but this seems to be giving me the maximum number of 0s in cases where there is only a single 1. Any way to return 0 in that case if there are no gaps between 1s OR there aren't multiple 1s

Comment: This formula throws an error for me.

Comment: @Blackcat I missed a closing parenthesis off the end, but otherwise works?

Comment: @plumtick sorry, I missed the part where it _had_ to be bookended by 1s, i.e., 00101 returns 1 and 0001 wasn't valid / 0. Tom has you covered though.

Answer (score 2):

You could discard any run of zeroes not bounded by ones which may be what OP  has in mind.

Perhaps by using Frequency and ignoring the first and last bins:

```
=LET(cols,A2:Y2,seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(cols)),
IFERROR(MAX(DROP(DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(cols=0,seq),IF(cols<>0,seq)),1),-1)),0))
```

or by using the lambda as proposed by @SSLinky but removing leading and trailing zeroes first:

```
=LET(cols,A2:Y2,
range,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1,cols,cols):XLOOKUP(1,cols,cols,,0,-1),1),
MAX(SCAN(0,range,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v=1,0,IF(v=0,a+1,a))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This `SEQUENCE/FREQUENCY` is terrific.